# Getting content from URL returns strange characters

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding, servlet-3.0

I am using this method to get the content from an url:

```
public String getContentFromURL(String stringUrl) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String content = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        StringBuilder builder;
        try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
            builder = new StringBuilder();
            int byteRead;
            while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1)
                builder.append((char) byteRead);
        }
        content=builder.toString();
        return content;
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return content;
}
```

It works ok for most files i get except for the ones that are characters from another languages eg: `áí` etc... instead of those characters i get `�`.

1. I have tried setting tomcat conector as this:

   ```
          <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
          connectionTimeout="20000"
          redirectPort="8443" />
   ```
2. Page encoding as: `<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`
3. Added this in the servlet aswell:

   ```
   response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   ```
4. Tried decoding content as GZIP.

None of the options above worked for me.

This is the url im trying to get the content from:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kpbrx26bwhoa1rp/moment.js?raw=1
```

Its a file in dropbox that even the browser can read correctly, using `raw=1` to get straight the content of the file. In browser, try searching for `"[Môre om]` to check if it displays correctly.

**What is the proper way of getting content from URLs that contain strange characters?**

PD: using notepad++ im sure its encoding is utf-8
[image: dropbox]

PD2: getting character encode from the connection returns null.

**Update:** tried this code using [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library:

```
        String content = "";
        URLConnection url = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/kpbrx26bwhoa1rp/moment.js?raw=1").openConnection();

        InputStream stream = url.getInputStream();
        content = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(stream, Charsets.UTF_8));
        Closeables.closeQuietly(stream);

        try (PrintStream outText = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\test.txt"))) {
            outText.print(content);
            outText.close();
        }
```

It does work on plain java project and all characters appear correctly but NOT on Java Web App project, this is my index where I tried this method:

```
<%@page import="java.io.PrintStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="com.google.common.io.Closeables"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStreamReader"%>
<%@page import="com.google.common.io.CharStreams"%>
<%@page import="com.google.common.base.Charsets"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.net.URLConnection"%>
<%@page import="java.net.URL"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String content = "";
        URLConnection url = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/kpbrx26bwhoa1rp/moment.js?raw=1").openConnection();

        InputStream stream = url.getInputStream();
        content = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(stream, Charsets.UTF_8));
        Closeables.closeQuietly(stream);

        try (PrintStream outText = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\test.txt"))) {
            outText.print(content);
            outText.close();
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

When I look into the created file these `�` still appear. **Why does the same code behave differently from standalone app to web app?**

**SOLVED:** replacing

```
try (PrintStream outText = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\test.txt"))) {
            outText.print(content);
            outText.close();
        }
```

with

```
Writer outText = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\testRaw.txt"), "UTF-8"));
        try {
            outText.write(content);
        } finally {
            outText.close();
        }
```

Comment: You should get the character set from the URLConnection, not just assume it's UTF-8.

Comment: And 'being sure' is no reason to hard-code something that is available dynamically.

Comment: @EJP character encode from the connection returns null...

Comment: Since you're in a JSP page, just output some of what you're getting back on the page itself. Then you can skip the files and the outbound encoding, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write the text in the default encoding, better store it as UTF-8.

```
try (PrintStream outText = new PrintStream(
        new File("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\test.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
    if (!content.startsWith("\uFEFF")) {
        outText.print("\uFEFF");
    }
    outText.print(content);
} // Calls outText.close()
```

This writes the text also with a BOM char `'\uFEFF'` at the beginning. That is an invisible zero-width space, that Windows can use to detect UTF-8. It is a bad practice actually, but allows to edit the text in NotePad.

The error was that some Unicode character was not mappable to the default encoding.

An aside: you are assuming that the text from the URL is in UTF-8. In general it would be better to check it by the URLConnection headers.

```
String encoding = urlc.getContentEncoding();
if (encoding == null) {
    encoding = "UTF-8";
} else if (encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("ISO-8859-1")) { // Latin-1
    encoding = "Windows-1252"; // Windows Latin-1
}
```

The Latin-1 patch might be useful as all browsers on any operating system interprete ISO-8859-1 as Windows-1252; now officially for HTML5.

Comment: The BOM is superfluous, since the user is looking at the output in chrome/notepad++.

Comment: @JoopEggen there is no constructor for String,String when creating file.  http://www.mediafire.com/view/w7gwaupilkg4p98/Untitled.png

Comment: @Alpha2k PrintWriter(OutputStreamWriter(etc is what you want. that has a char encoding param

Comment: @pvg mentions the more usual PrintWriter, with which I am more familiar. The constructor cannot use `(FileOutputStream, String)` hence changed it to `(File, String)` in the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

I turned your code into a minimum example like so, while taking out the weird bits (the point of a BufferedReader is to avoid reading char by char). I get perfectly good UTF8 back. Try running this, redirecting to a file and examining the output with a Unicode-capable text editor.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class UTF8Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //System.out.println(getContentFromURL("http://www.columbia.edu/~kermit/utf8.html"));
        System.out.println(getContentFromURL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/kpbrx26bwhoa1rp/moment.js?raw=1"));
    }

    public static String getContentFromURL(String stringUrl) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = breader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: characters still appear as � and i used chrome to inspect the code.

Comment: What OS and version of Chrome are you using? Can you upload a copy of what you received somewhere?

Comment: easier, try getting the content from this url: http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js and then use that content in html like  <script src='script/moment.js'></script>

Comment: That doesn't make sense, I'm not the one having trouble getting a properly encoded file back, you are. Both of these urls work fine so it is much more likely this has something to do with your environment. Your OS, your JVM, maybe your fonts? Upload a copy of the data you receive so that can be eliminated.

Comment: Check the other answer, the default encoding on write is, well, I have no idea what it is on windows but you should set it explicitly.